# Citation style: pages punctuation

Tags: biblatex, citing, punctuation

Look at following `\autocite`-example:

> `\autocite[15]{kant}`
>
> Immanuel Kant: Freizeitparks im Harz, S. 15.

How can I change the comma into a period? For the bibliography it's easy. I can use:

```
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addperiod\addspace}
```

But for the citation?

Comment: What citation style are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, `biblatex` does not print the pages information there, but rather a `postnote`. As such we have to modify `\postnotedelim`.

```
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addperiod\space}
```

To prevent `biblatex` from capitalising the "p." after the period, we can go with

```
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addperiod\space\midsentence}
```

or

```
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\adddot\space}
```

Example code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addperiod\space\midsentence}
\begin{document}
  \autocite[15]{cicero}
\end{document}
```

---

A more complicated solution only prints the period if the postnote contains only page information, the standard delimiter is added otherwise.

```
\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\iffieldpages{postnote}
       {\setunit{\addperiod\space\midsentence}}
       {\setunit{\postnotedelim}}%
     \printfield{postnote}}}

\renewbibmacro*{multipostnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{multipostnote}
    {}
    {\iffieldpages{postnote}
       {\addperiod\space\midsentence}
       {\postnotedelim}%
     \printfield{multipostnote}}}
```

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\iffieldpages{postnote}
       {\setunit{\addperiod\space\midsentence}}
       {\setunit{\postnotedelim}}%
     \printfield{postnote}}}

\renewbibmacro*{multipostnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{multipostnote}
    {}
    {\iffieldpages{postnote}
       {\addperiod\space\midsentence}
       {\postnotedelim}%
     \printfield{multipostnote}}}

\begin{document}
  \autocite[15]{cicero}
\end{document}
```

Both give

> (Cicero 1995. p. 15)